# Use a var within a selector

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if this is possible:

Having executed a PHP script with get..

```
var splitup = response.split(',');
var first = splitup[0];
$("#somediv").html(first);
```

(Trying to replace `#somediv` with the value of `first`).

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did you mean to say `var first = splitup[0];`? (otherwise you'll just get the first character of `response`, assuming that's a string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jquery selectors are just strings.

You can certainly do this:

```
$("#"+variableName).html('your content');
```

You didn't say what you wanted to actually put inside the div, but I'm assuming from the question that the value of first is actually the name of the div you want to put into the jQuery selector. So it would look like this

```
$("#"+first).html('some content');
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what this does?

Comment: + is the javscript string [concatenator](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp). It adds two strings together. So if var a='hello' and b=' world', a+b will be 'hello world'.. A jQuery selector is just a string, so it can be manipulated (or, in this case, dynamically constructed on the fly) like any other string.    I'll edit my answer a little to make it more clear.